# Re-coloring image preserving luminance

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Given an input image, I was thinking about how the image could be re-colored to a single new color keeping the luminance of the image similar to what it was earlier. 
So I wrote a naive code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat img = imread("test2.png", 1);
    Mat hsv; cvtColor(img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);    
    vector<Mat > channels;split(hsv, channels);
    Mat luminance; channels[2].copyTo(luminance);
    Mat res; img.copyTo(res);
    channels.clear(); split(res, channels);
    for (int i = 0; i<res.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<res.cols; j++) {
            channels[0].at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
            channels[1].at<uchar>(i, j) = 0; 
            channels[2].at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }
    merge(channels, res);
    cvtColor(res, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    channels.clear(); split(hsv, channels);
    luminance.copyTo(channels[2]);
    merge(channels, res);
    cvtColor(res, res, CV_HSV2BGR);
    imwrite("result.png", res);
    return 0;
}
```

What I actually did is just extracted the luminance map of the original image, then created an image with the color I want it to be in, and replaced the luminance map of this output image with the luminance map of input image.
But resultant image seems to be darker in shade. Is there any better way to do this?
Input image:
[image: This is the input image.]
Resulting image:
[image: This is output which I am getting, which is darker.]

Comment: Could you, please, attach your input image, as well as the current result. It would be great if you could perhaps use some graphics editor and generate some image that shows your expected result, and attach that as well.

Comment: @DanMašek added :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for *"tinting"*. I don't have any references for how you to do it with **OpenCV** but there is a description in Anthony Thyssen's excellent **ImageMagick** notes [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#tinting) - search for the word "somehow". Maybe you can adapt it to **OpenCV**, if the effect is what you seek.

At the command-line, with **ImageMagick**, I did this:

```
convert drop.png -fill red -tint 50% result.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way in Imagemagick.

```
convert \( input.png -colorspace gray \) \( -clone 0 -fill red -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 \) -compose colorize -composite result1.png
```

[image: grayscale = rec709luma result]

```
convert \( input.png -colorspace lab -channel red -separate \) \( -clone 0 -fill red -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 \) -compose colorize -composite result2.png
```

[image: lab luminance result]

```
convert \( input.png -colorspace hsi -channel blue -separate \) \( -clone 0 -fill red -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 \) -compose colorize -composite result3.png
```

[image: hsi intensity result]

Choose what colorspace represents the intensity/luminance you want to use. See my script, color2gray at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/color2gray/index.php to see what different colorspace intensity/luminance show as gray.